# execSync hangs in Docker container but works as expected locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, curl, child-process

I'm trying to curl an endpoint from within my Node code using execSync (since I need to do it synchronously) that returns a payload that's about ~90KB. This works perfectly fine locally but inside a Docker container the following line hangs:

```
const { execSync } = require('child_process');

return execSync(
    `curl -X DELETE "https://foo.com"`
);
```

Here's my Dockerfile setup as well:

```
# Base image to match prod node version (deploy-swarm: 6.9.4) (Jenkins2: 4.2.6)
FROM node:6.9.4-alpine

# Make the working directory folder
WORKDIR /cloudinary-batch-jobs

# Install dependencies with npm
COPY *.npmrc package.json package-lock.json /tmp/
RUN cd /tmp && /usr/local/bin/npm install --production
RUN mv /tmp/node_modules /cloudinary-batch-jobs

# Copy all files into working directory
COPY . /cloudinary-batch-jobs

# Get curl
RUN apk --update --no-cache add curl

CMD node /cloudinary-batch-jobs/index.js
```

Comment: Can you try the `spawnSync` option and see if it helps?

Comment: The curl just hangs exactly how execSync does. With `execSync` I've tried setting { stdio: `inherit` } as an option and it seems to help the curl not hang at least. But I need to capture the output is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was logging the buffered response afterwards; after I removed this log, the curl stops hanging and it works with both `execSync` and `spawnSync` actually.

Comment: Might be that buffer was causing a read on a empty stream and causing it to hang?